# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed at classloader.php

Tags: drupal

After installing the latest version of CiviCRM (5.56.1) I cannot open my website anymore and log is showing this message:

Got error 'PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" at /data/sites/web/instituutvlaamsevolkskunstbe/cms-install/4466-instituut-voor-vlaamse-volkskunst/production/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php line 85'

and drush cr returns:

Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Drupal version 9.5.0
PHP version 7.4.33

I cannot find anything related

Thanks,
Stefaan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer 2.5.1, just released, fixed this. Run `composer self-update`, then `composer install` on the site to update the class loader.

[Composer 2.5 is not compatible with civi, yet](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4046). Use `composer self-update --rollback` for now; then run `composer install` again on your site.